# Using an extended version of a parent variable in a child class in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, parent-child, extends

I have an extending class which needs to use and extended version of a variable in the parent class. So far I've been getting away with using it like this:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    protected ParentVariable variable;

    public ParentClass(){
        this.variable = new ParentVariable();
    }
    ....
}

public class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    public ChildClass(){
        super();
        this.variable = new ChildVariable();
        //Where ChildVariable Extends ParentVariable
        ....
    }
}
```

This more or less works so long as every time I use variable I cast it to ChildVarible but this is ugly and throws up some issues. Is there a better way to perform this? Thanks.

Comment: Unclear: why do you need to cast it at all times if all methods from superclass are visible in subclass as well.

Comment: Where is the variable defined in ChildClass?

Comment: @EugeneS I think that OP forgot to mention `ChildClass` extends `ParentClass` in his code.

Comment: Assuming `ChildVariable` extends `ParentVariable` then you could parameterise `ParentClass` as `class ParentClass<T>` defining the variable as `T variable`. Then do `class ChildClass extends ParentClass<ChildVariable>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's possible to make your superclass abstract, you could solve this by using generics:

```
public abstract class ParentClass<T extends ParentVariable>
{
    private T variable;

    protected T getVariable(){
        return variable
    }

    protected void setVariable(T variable){
        this.variable = variable;
    }
    ....
}

public class ChildClass extends ParentClass<ChildVariable>
{
    public ChildClass() {
        setVariable(new ChildVariable());
        //Where ChildVariable Extends ParentVariable
        ChildVariable foo = getVariable() // no cast nessecary
    }
}
```

Notice that I made your field private. You should always access field by getter and setter methods, even in subclasses.

If this is not possible (maybe even if it was) it is an indicator that your design is flawed. Refactoring of all for classes might be needed to achieve a clean architecture. Unfortunately this depends on the whole implementation of all four classes and possibly the whole context those classes are used in. An answer to that would be too broad for stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is a really interesting solution but unfortunately I cannot make my parent class abstract.